# VBA code which can open and save file in any application

Tags: vba, file, save

Can u suggest a VBA code which can open and save file in any(ex:autocad) application? Ex: I would like to open multiple autocad .dwg files in Autocad application and save the same.regards Anand SN

Answer (score 0):

You can open any file in it's native program using

```
Shell "CMD /C START " & myFileName
```

because the operating system manages file type associations.

Saving would require an API from that particular software, no programming language can do that without the use of an external library because it is the responsibility of the *software*, not the *operating system*